# CSS3 Transition: how to add transition on hover to this div?

Tags: html, css

I add some content on this div that will be visible on hover.

It work till here: [jsbin.com/ipajas/](http://jsbin.com/ipajas/)

But as the content is loaded dynamically, I don't know it's exactly the content's height. So I change the height from `height:250px;` to `height:auto;` 
And the problem is: in that case, the transition don't work anymore. [jsbin.com/ipajas/2](http://jsbin.com/ipajas/2)

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<a>
    <div class="divabsence" id="id" onClick="expand()">
        chose your color:

        <p> red <input type="checkbox" id="button"></p>
        <p> blue <input type="checkbox" id="button"></p>
        <p> green <input type="checkbox" id="button"></p>
        <p> white <input type="checkbox" id="button"></p>

    </div> 
</a>
```

CSS:

```
 .divcolor
    {
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    transition:  1s; 

  overflow:hidden;
    }

    .divcolor:hover
    {
    height:auto; 
    }
```

***UPDATE***

It seems to be impossible so, I've just add this as a temporary solution:
 `height: 150px; overflow:scroll;` [jsbin.com/ulodil/4](http://jsbin.com/ulodil/4)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CSS Specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#animatable-css) only length, percentage, or calc are valid types, not auto.

Instead of `height` you can use `max-height` with a big enough value:

```
.divcolor
{
  max-height:30px;
  ...
}

.divcolor:hover
{
  max-height: 1000px; <- something just big enough for your needs 
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is, I don't want a long scrolling if the content is not that long as there is something else like a confirmation button after the content

Comment: `max-height` is kind of the same as `auto`, but with an upper limit. It's only as large as the content, but not larger than `1000px` :)

Comment: I see, The content vary from 10 to 100. So you know... I've just add this as a temporary solution:  `height: 150px;
      overflow:scroll; `

Answer (score 1):

You could load everything into a `<ul>` and set the height dynamically based off the number of `<li>` elements. Depending on how the content is loaded dynamically you could do it through JavaScript or some server-side scripting.

You could add as many or as little `<li>` elements and the height will adjust.

[JSBIN - Sample Here](http://jsbin.com/efewad/1/)

```
function adjustHeight()
{
  var itemList = document.getElementById('color-list');
  var items = itemList.getElementsByTagName('li');

  var listHeight = items.length * 25;

  document.getElementById('id').style.height = (50 + listHeight) + "px";

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know JavaSript can give me solution, but I was experiencing CSS3 limit... Thank you anyway